# Redshift - unsupported type "serial" for auto increment id with node-orm-2

Tags: node.js, amazon-redshift, node-orm2

Any insight on how to get an auto increment id working? From my understanding, an id column is added by default; however, because I'm using Redshift, the default "serial" type won't work as it is not supported.

```
{ [error: Column "probe.id" has unsupported type "serial".]
  name: 'error',
  length: 165,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '0A000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: '/home/awsrsqa/padb/src/pg/src/backend/parser/parser_analyze.c',
  line: '3600',
  routine: 'transformColumnDefinition',
  model: 'probe' }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No such thing supported.

You can only get an [auto-increment for an integer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html):

> `IDENTITY(seed, step)`
> Clause that specifies that the column is an `IDENTITY` column. An `IDENTITY` column contains unique auto-generated values. These values start with the value specified as seed and increment by the number specified as step. The data type for an `IDENTITY` column must be either `INT` or `BIGINT`.

For a GUID you will have to generate one and insert it yourself.

**Example:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table(
   id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
);
```

Comment: Possible for somebody to add a SQL create table example of this?